# Какая тут будет формула на определение минимального значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

В двумерном массиве [[40, 14, 22, 17], [80, 19, 37, 51], [7, 20, 35, 55]] определите
минимальный элемент в каждой строке.

Comment: что именно не получается? Каждая строка это отдельный списко, для определения минимального элемента списка есть даже отдельная специальная функция, даже придумывать ничего не надо.

Comment: Покажите Вашу попытку решения, если что не получилось поправим, а решать задачки с нуля как-то не правильно все же учитесь Вы а не мы..

Comment: сейчас дополню вопрос

Comment: Определил: 14, 19 и 7.

Comment: все,вопрос сам решил)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [[40, 14, 22, 17], [80, 19, 37, 51], [7, 20, 35, 55]]
print(*map(min, arr))
```